# Why use Gulp to wrap HTML templates if some plugins don't support streams?

Tags: html, node.js, gulp

We know: Gulp works with Node streams. But some plugins, like the very useful template wrappers, don't support streams. This is a common pattern in their source code:

```
if (file.isStream()) {
  return cb(new PluginError('gulp-[plugin]', 'streaming not supported'));
}

if (file.isBuffer()) {
  // do whole file transform
}
```

Well, this **whole file based transform** can be done directly with Node's `fs` module.

*So, in this scenario, what's the point of using Gulp?*

Comment: I suspect the answer revolves around the situation where, for a developer with a certain level of experience, a library seems like a good idea but processing a template as a stream is harder to implement than processing a template using whole-file transforms. They add Gulp because "streams are good, right?" but don't understand why, or even notice, that this doesn't work the way they envision.

Comment: @Ouroborus, Your note is what I suspect. I'm reading about the "backpressure" problem in data handling. Maybe it is the advantage of using Gulp custom API for streams. But, backpressure seems to be a low-level issue on data transfer. So the question...